# Printing all factor levels as a list in a shiny dashboard

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to print all levels of a factor in a shiny dashboard. I know I could easily do that by:

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Testing shiny App"),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("my_levels_list")
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

        output$my_levels_list <- renderUI({
            HTML(levels(iris$Species))
        })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But all the results are outputed within the same row:

```
<div id="my_levels_list" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output">setosa versicolor virginica</div>
```

What I would like to have is something like this instead:

```
<div id="my_levels_list" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output">
<ul><li>setosa</li> <li>versicolor</li> <li>virginica</li></ul></div>
```

I tried with more extravagant code like:

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Testing shiny App"),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("my_levels_list")
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$my_levels_list <- renderUI({
        for (i in iris$Species) {
            HTML(i)
        }
    })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But nothing is outputted.

Comment: try
`output$my_levels_list <- renderUI({ tags$ul(lapply(levels(iris$Species), tags$li)) })`

Comment: Great! it works perfectly, and very concise. I didn't know about the tags function, thanks for pointing that out. If you want to add your comment as a reply, I will gladly mark it as resolved.